Understanding applying of input argument parameters to the Terraform CDKTF synth/deploy processes flow
I believe that there are some theoretical/technical aspects of the Terraform CDKTF that I've misunderstood

I have a IaaC C#-based application that I created with the Terraform CDKTF technology.
Essentially, I started off the solution creation with the following command in Dos command prompt:

C:\BlahBlah\CodeDirectory\BlahBlah>cdktf init --template=csharp
--providers=kreuzwerker/docker --local

I’ve developed the code by creating an AWS Lambda Project within the aforementioned solution via Visual Studio 2022
When I build, the  AWS Lambda Project, the contents are within the following directory:

C:\BlahBlah\CodeDirectory\BlahAWSLambdaProjectBlahBlah\bin\Debug\net6.0\

I wanted to pass the aforementioned AWS Lambda Project’s deployable content directory as an input argument for the Terraform CDKTF synth/deploy processes flow:

deployableContentDirectoryPath="C:\
BlahBlah\CodeDirectory\BlahAWSLambdaProjectBlahBlah\bin\Debug\net6.0\"

I ran the following command:

C:\BlahBlah\CodeDirectory\BlahBlah>  cdktf synth
--var-file="inputfile.tfvars"

And subsequently, I also ran the following command:

C:\BlahBlah\CodeDirectory\BlahBlah>  cdktf deploy
--var-file="inputfile.tfvars"

For both the aforementioned commands execution runs, the following error is thrown when the point of execution reaches code that uses the deployableContentDirectoryPath variable within the Terraform CDKTF IaaC C#-based application:

⠴  Synthesizing [2024-04-11T11:24:29.266] [ERROR] default -
System.Exception: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat
'${TfToken[TOKEN.0]}'

I thought that during the Terraform CDKTF synthesis process, the input argument parameters do get applied, so why is it still referring to Tokens in the synthesis process as opposed to the actual value ( i.e. "C:\ BlahBlah\CodeDirectory\BlahAWSLambdaProjectBlahBlah\bin\Debug\net6.0\" )?
During the Terraform CDKTF synth/deploy processes flow, at what point do the input argument parameters get applied to the Terraform CDKTF IaaC C#-based application code?

I see you are upset with the downvotes ... Do you honestly believe that with the information you have provided someone can reproduce your problem? Would you consider that a minimal reproducible example?
